# TypeScript: Discriminate union from value in a tuple

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is it possible to discriminate a union type based on the first element in a tuple property?

e.g.

```
type Landing = {
  tokens: ['landing']
};

type Month = {
  tokens: ['month', string]
};

type Day = {
  tokens: ['day', string, string]
};

type Route =
  | Month
  | Day
  | Landing;

let route: Route = getRoute();

if(route.tokens[0] === 'day') {
  // resolve to Day type
}
```

UPDATE:
If there's not a direct way to do this, I would be happy with a custom type guard but haven't been able to get one working yet. To clarify, I'd want a typeguard that can discriminate the union as opposed to explicit check for each variant.

e.g.

```
if(typeGuard(route, 'day')) {
    // compiler knows this id Day type
}
else if(typeGuard(route, 'month')) {
    // compiler knows this is Month type
}
```

Comment: Not without custom type guards..Types for index access aren't tracked by the compiler for performance reasons as far as I know.

Comment: When you use `route.tokens[1]` inside the if-block, it resolves it to type string, and `route.tokens` resolves to `['day', string, string]`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Any ideas on how to write a custom typeguard for this? That would be an acceptable answer for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**
Since the orginal answer, typescript has gotten better at discrimitating unions, so this works as expected with typescript 3.3:

```
if (route.tokens[0] === "day") {
    // resolve to Day type
    route.tokens[0] === 'day'
} else if (route.tokens[0] === "landing") {
    // resolve to Landing type
    route.tokens[0] === 'landing'
} else {
    // resolve to Month type
    route.tokens[0] === 'month'
}
```

**Orignial**

While the solution to write a type-guard for each union member is a perfectly valid one, it does create problems if there are many members of the union or if you later add extra memebers to the union.

You can create a custom type guard that guards for all possible types using the `Extract` conditional type:

```
type Landing = {
    tokens: ['landing']
};

type Month = {
    tokens: ['month', string]
};

type Day = {
    tokens: ['day', string, string]
};

type Route =
    | Month
    | Day
    | Landing;

declare let route: Route;

function isRoute<T extends Route['tokens'][0]>(r: Route, type: T): r is Extract<Route, { tokens: [T, ...any[]] }> {
    return route.tokens[0] === type;
}

if (isRoute(route, 'day')) {
    // resolve to Day type
    route.tokens[0] === 'day'
} else if (isRoute(route, 'landing')) {
    // resolve to Landing type
    route.tokens[0] === 'landing'
} else {
    // resolve to Month type
    route.tokens[0] === 'month'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Landing%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tokens%3A%20%5B'landing'%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Month%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tokens%3A%20%5B'month'%2C%20string%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Day%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tokens%3A%20%5B'day'%2C%20string%2C%20string%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Route%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20Month%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20Day%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20Landing%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20route%3A%20Route%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isRoute%3CT%20extends%20Route%5B'tokens'%5D%5B0%5D%3E(r%3A%20Route%2C%20type%3A%20T)%3A%20r%20is%20Extract%3CRoute%2C%20%7B%20tokens%3A%20%5BT%2C%20...any%5B%5D%5D%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20route.tokens%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20type%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isRoute(route%2C%20'day'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20resolve%20to%20Day%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route.tokens%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'day'%0D%0A%7D%20else%20if%20(isRoute(route%2C%20'landing'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20resolve%20to%20Landing%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route.tokens%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'landing'%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20resolve%20to%20Month%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route.tokens%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'month'%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I think the spread any[] on the tuple is the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Using typeguards it will be something like this:

```
type Landing = {
  tokens: ['landing']
};
const isLanding = (x: any): x is Landing => x[0] === 'landing'

type Month = {
  tokens: ['month', string]
};
const isMonth = (x: any): x is Month => x[0] === 'month'

type Day = {
  tokens: ['day', string, string]
};
const isDay = (x: any): x is Day => x[0] === 'day'

type Route =
  | Month
  | Day
  | Landing;

let route: Route = getRoute();

if(isDay (route)) {
  // resolve to Day type
}
```

You can find more information on type guard in the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (search for type guard)

Hopes it answers your question ;)

Comment: To clarify, I would want a type guard that can discriminate the union type. Something like if(isRoute(route, 'day')) else if (isRoute(route, 'month')) ...

Comment: what it is you don't like in the current solution? For the solution you propose i'm not sure but it doesn't seem to be feasible, but besides that your function isRoute as written it's returns type what do you want it to be? a Route? that doesn't helps you. You might want to `infer` stuff but the code will quickly becomes dirty imo - here you juste have 4 lines and it works well - no need for complicates typings

Comment: It doesn't do what I am asking for. I would have to write a type guard for each variant of the union. I am wanting a way to discriminate the type.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript added support for control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions in [v4.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions).

```
type Action =
  | { kind: "NumberContents"; payload: number }
  | { kind: "StringContents"; payload: string };

function processAction(action: Action) {
  const { kind, payload } = action;
  if (kind === "NumberContents") {
    let num = payload * 2;
    // ...
  } else if (kind === "StringContents") {
    const str = payload.trim();
    // ...
  }
}
```